# Access store inside component method : Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i want to get a state inside my store.

My simplified methods:

```
export default {
  methods: {
      getServiceFromStore(serviceID) {
          serviceID.forEach(function (id) {
            console.log(this.$store.state.metiers)
          })
      }
  }
}
```

On the Chrome Developper Tool, I can see that `$store` is defined, but I don't understand why it's not working.

[image]

My method is executed on the `beforeMount()` hook

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not create a store action, mutation and getter? You would call the mapped action from your page component's `fetch` property method and call the mapped getter in your nested component's `computed` property.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, i need to use a arrow function to use $this from the context.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this